# Are definitions these of Big-O notation equivalent to the standard?

Tags: asymptotics, nonstandard-analysis

This definition uses hyper-reals and nonstandard analysis.

Let $k^*(x)$ be the natural extension of $k(x)$. Let $f$ and $g$ be functions.

$f = O(g) := \frac {f^*(H)} {g^*(H)}$ is finite for all positive unlimited $H$.

$f=\Omega(g) := \frac {g^*(H)} {f^*(H)}$ is finite for all positive unlimited $H$.

$f=\Theta(g):=f=O(g) \wedge f=\Omega(g)$

$f=o(g):=\frac {f^*(H)} {g^*(H)}$ is infinitesimal for all positive unlimited $H$.

$f=\omega(g):=\frac {g^*(H)} {f^*(H)}$ is infinitesimal for all positive unlimited $H$.

Comment: Your definition of $o$ is not equivalent to the standard one. Consider $f(x) = 1 + \sin x$, $g(x) = 1$. Then $f \in O(g)$ as $f \le 2g$, $g \not\in O(f)$, as $\inf \alpha f = 0$ for each $\alpha \ge 0$, but $f \not\in o(g)$, as $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=f(x)\not \to 0$ for $x\to \infty$. Same holds for your $\omega$.

Comment: One flaw. $g \in O(f)$ is true, as $\frac {1}{1+sin(H)}$ is in fact finite (although its specific value starts to depend on the ultra power construction. That is alright though, we only need to know it is finite.)

Comment: Then your $O$ isn't the standard one. As for the standard $O$, we have $g \not\in O(f)$. Or in other words: For the standard definitions of $O, \Omega, o$, there are functions $f,g$ with $f \in O(g)$, $g \not\in O(f)$, $f \not\in o(g)$. For your definitions, that can't happen. So your definitions cannot be equivalent to the standard ones.

Comment: Fixed. Now your f and g are false for all of these (as I presume they are for the standard definitions.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Omega- and Theta- notations, but the big-O and little-o definitions are correct.  There is a bit of an ambiguity in your notation since you didn't specify where $x$ tends to exactly, but I assume $x$ is increasing without bound.

To respond to robjohn's question: as far as comparison between the traditional and the hyperreal approaches, the little-o and big-O example is not particularly enlightening.  A better example is the definition of continuity of a function $f$.  You are probably aware of the fact that a majority of undergraduates never fully master the traditional $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of continuity. It may come as more of a surprise that Cauchy never defined continuity using $\epsilon,\delta$.  In fact, Cauchy defined continuity in terms of the property that an infinitesimal $x$-increment necessarily produces an infinitesimal change in $y=f(x)$.  This is what the hyperreal definition says, as well.

Comment: Would you care to discuss why these are equivalent to the standard definition of big-O and little-o? Some discussion about the differences between standard and non-standard analysis might be nice.

Comment: Since the OP talks about "positive unlimited $H$", it seems safe to assume that in the real case, they are talking about $x\to\infty$.

Comment: With hyper-reals, values do not tend to infinity. It is a formalized notion of infinity.

Comment: @PyRulez: I think what robjohn was pointing out is that, on the "standard" side, when the OP speaks of $k(x)$ and the behavior of big and little O, he means "behavior as $x$ tends to infinity".